# Janu Gridex EndCustomEdit event

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, gridex

we are using Janu GridEX v4 in our C# applications. To configure the row we are using gridex custom controls

As soon as we click on the columns dropdown InitCustomEdit event gets triggered and when the focus is shifted to any other column EndCustomEdit event gets triggered. Is this the way EndCustomEdit event should work? If so, is there any alternative so as soon as the value from the dropdown is selected and displayed on the row EndCustomEdit event should get triggered.

Example: I have three dropdown columns in a gridex row : col1, col2 and col3. There is an end to end mapping between col1 and col3, when I click on the col1 dropdown InitCustomEdit event gets triggered and after selecting the value and clicking on col2 EndCustomEdit of col1 gets triggered and col3 value gets auto populate.

Expected: As soon as I select the value from the col1, col3 value should get auto populated.

Comment: please add your code for more details.

Comment: I think you can refer to this link, may be it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728212/gridex-item-population-on-the-fly

Comment: For your reference its not Janu , its Janus GridEx , website : http://www.janusys.com/